# Unable to boot into safe mode in Windows 8.1, display driver failure

Tags: windows-8.1, safe-mode

Shift + F8 does **NOT** work. I am unable to use the UI to select safe boot or enter commands reliably (the screen is all random colors).

Is there a 100% keyboard driven way to enter safe mode? I am able to boot into what barely appears to be the default user's desktop (or some random user, can't tell which for sure).

Comment: Well, i know a trick. If you reset the machine every time Windows tries to boot, eventually the third time it should launch the Auto Repair thing. It will diagnose the PC but it will fail. From there, i select Advanced Opions instead of Restart and you get some options.

Comment: Thank you. I did that and was able to select some options that finally enabled safe mode.

Comment: I guess i've wasted my ability to answer : p (previously i wasn't sure if i should answer or comment :)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i know a trick. If you reset the machine every time Windows tries to boot, eventually the third time it should launch the Auto Repair thing. It will diagnose the PC but it will fail. From there, i select Advanced Opions instead of Restart and you get some options.